# How to improve performence of this Haskell code?

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, set, parallel-processing, lazy-evaluation

I'm facing the following problem :

From the initial set `[1,2,3,4]` compute all possible subsets i.e `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4],[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]`

I've wrote the following Haskell program `generate.hs` which is correct.

```
generateSets :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
generateSets []  _  _  = []
generateSets src [] _  = let isets = growthup [] src in generateSets src iset iset
generateSets src sets rsets = if null sets' then rsets else generateSets src sets' (rsets++sets')
  where sets' = concatMap (flip growthup src) sets

growthup :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
growthup ps ss = map (\suf -> ps++[suf]) ss'
  where ss' = nextoccurence ps ss

nextoccurence :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
nextoccurence [] ys = ys
nextoccurence xs ys = tail ys'
  where ys' = dropWhile (/= last xs) ys
```

While executing it in the GHC interpreter *ghci* ...

```
ghci> generate [1,2,3,4] [] []
ghci> [[1],[2],[3],[4],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4],[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

every thing goes fine but the program take too long for just small sets of size 30 for example.

My question is : It is possible to improve my code in order to gain more from haskell laziness, or garbagge collector or something else ?

Is my code a good candidate for parallelism ?

Thanks for any reply !

Comment: Try to come up with a version that does not depend on `Eq`. It could be both more efficient and easier to understand. Also, your program misses the empty subset.

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of `subsequences` in `Data.List`. Also, a set of size 30 has `2^30` subsets, so there's only so much you can do in terms of efficiency, as the size of the output is exponential in the size of the input.

Comment: Does the order of the subsets matter or will any order do?

Comment: You are missing [] (the empty subset) btw, but anyways the algorithm is O(2^n) or expenonential in the size of the list. While some optimizations could be made, if you are going to iterate through the list it is slow anyways

Comment: Also, you're interpreting the code. Try compiling it for a free 30x speedup. (`ghc -O2`).

Comment: As n.m. said, avoid `Eq`.  A subset generator that depends on equality is wrong.

Comment: There are 2^30 subsets of a set of size 30, with 15 elements on average. So if you're going to print all the elements of all the subsets (discounting brackets, commas and other details), then for a set of size 30 you're going to need about (2^30*15)/(2^16*8) = 30720 times as much time as for a set of size 16. My GHCi says it takes about 5 seconds to print out the result of `Data.List.subsequences [1..16]`; I therefore expect `subsequences [1..30]` to take nearly two days! The big question is: what do you want to do with all those subsets?

Comment: @danielfisher the order doen't really matter. Any ways thank to all your reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sets have a *lot* of subsets. In fact, a set of *n* elements has *2<sup>n</sup>* subsets, so a set of 30 elements has over one billion subsets. Whichever method you use to generate them, even iterating over the results is going to take a long time. For larger sets you can pretty much forget about going through them all before the heat death of the universe.

So there's only so much you can do performance-wise, as even doubling the speed of your algorithm will only let you work with lists of one more element in the same time. **For most applications, the real solution is to avoid having to enumerate all the subsets in the first place.**

That said, there is a simple inductive way of thinking about subsets which makes defining a proper subset function easy without having to do any equality comparisons, which solves some of the problems with your implementation.

For the base case, the empty set has one subset: the empty set.

```
subsets [] = [[]]
```

For a set with at least one element `(x:xs)`, we have the subsets which contain that element, and the ones that don't. We can get the subsets that don't contain `x` by recursively calling `subsets xs`, and we can get the rest by prepending `x` to those.

```
subsets (x:xs) = subsets xs ++ map (x:) (subsets xs)
```

The definition of [`subsequences`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#subsequences) in `Data.List` works on the same principle, but in a slightly more optimized way, which also returns the subsets in a different order and makes better use of sharing. However, as I said, enumerating the subsets of a list of length 30 is going to be slow no matter what, and your best bet is to try to avoid having to do it in the first place.